# JavaScript Timeout Function

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking in other posts for the answer, but the answers never seem to work in my favor. I'm trying to make an image fade when the page finishes loading. I've figured out I can loop until the counter reaches 0 (when image is invisible) and fade the image slowly.

The problem is, the setTimeout() function doesn't seem to be working.
Here's the code:

```js
function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      //A comment said something about looping,
      //but it was confusing to understand...
    }, 50);
}

function setup() {
  var load = document.getElementById('img');
  load.style.opacity = 0 //Start at being visible
  for (var i = 10; i > 0; i = i - 0.1) { //For loop
    load.style.opacity = i; //Use the index variable and use that to set the opacity
    setTimeout(); //Set the timeout, but this function does not pause the program for some reason...
    //I need to pause for 0.05 seconds.
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup, true); //Add event listener for when the page is done loading
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="img">
        <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" width="200" height="150">
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I put the javascript in a seperate file, I just can't access it from Stack Overflow...

Can someone help? And also, sometimes the image can be finicky at times as well, like sometimes it won't hide like it's supposed to do. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you *were* calling `timeout`, that won't make it pause until it's finished. The callback you're giving to `setTimeout` will run after that period of time but the rest of your code will continue running as normal. You'll still be setting `load.style.opacity = 0` almost instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function instead of a loop

```js
var load = document.getElementById('img');

function setup() {
  load.style.opacity = "1"; //Start at being visible

  timeout(1);
}

function timeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    i -= 0.1;
    if(i<=0)
      return;
    load.style.opacity = i.toString();
    timeout(i);
  }, 200);
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup, true); //Add event listener for when the page is done loading
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" width="200" height="150" id="img">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared a `setTimeout` without arguments, hence the error:

```
'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present."
```

Give it the appropriate amount of arguments:

```
for (var i = 10; i > 0; i = i - 0.1) { //For the loop
    load.style.opacity = i; 
    setTimeout(functionName, milliseconds); 
}
```

If you intended to use your `timeout()` function instead, call it. You're just instantiating a new `setTimeout` from the one you already created in the `timeout()` function.

Comment: I noticed that there was an error, but I had already posted it :(

Comment: Then feel free to mark one of ours as the answer, and call it a day. Next time, make absolutely sure there aren't any errors - the console is your best friend! :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to countdown the opacity with a recursive call. Here we are going from 1 down to 0 in 0.01 increments. The setTimeout will trigger the next recursive call after pausing for 50 msecs. These values, can of course, be adjusted as needed but the opacity needs to be a number from 1 (visible) to 0 (invisible).

```js
function setOpacity(el, lvl) {
 el.style.opacity = lvl;
}

function countDown(el, lvl) {
  function action(el, lvl) {
    return function () {
      countDown(el, lvl);
    }
  }
  setOpacity(el, lvl);
  if (lvl > 0) {
    lvl -= 0.01
    setTimeout(action(el, lvl), 50);
  }
}

function setup() {
  var load = document.getElementById('img');
  load.style.opacity = 1; //Start at being visible
  countDown(load, 1);
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup, true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="img">
        <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" width="200" height="150">
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, Ben. It is a little more verbose than some of the other answers but I thought that might help you get your head around what is going on. You can speed it up by changing the second parameter in the setTimeout from 50 to, say 10. That will make the fade 5 times faster. This number is the number of milliseconds that the image will stay at its current opacity level.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setup() {
 var load = document.getElementById('img');
 (function(){
  var i = 1;
  setTimeout(function () {
   i -= 0.1;
   load.style.opacity = i;
   if (i > 0) {
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
   }
  }, 100);
 })();
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup, true); //Add event listener for when the page is done loading
```

```html
      <div id="img">
        <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" width="200" height="150">
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about this?

Comment: Of course, this is a recursive function. arguments.callee is the same caller function. arguments is è object which contains properties about the function, I hope i explained it, sorry for my bad English